# How to create list from another typed list with 'List.from'?

Tags: list, types, intellij-idea, dart

Simple dart code:

```dart
class User {
  String name;
  User(this.name);
}

main() {
  List<User> users = [new User('Freewind')];
  var list = new List.from(users); 
  print(list.first.name); // ***
}
```

Notice the line ends with '// ***'.

My IDEA editor doesn't recognize `list.first` as a `User`, since it can't do the autocompletion when I typed '.name'.

So I have to declare the type:

```dart
List<User> list = new List.from(users);
```

It works but I want to know if there is any other way to let compiler know `list` has type `List<User>`?

I tried:

```dart
var list = new List<User>.from(users);
```

Which has wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me in DartEditor (no error/warning/hint) and of course executes successfully

```dart
var list = new List<User>.from(users);
```

Comment: I agree. The problem is that you are not creating a type list anywhere.
To create a typed list with `List.from` you must write it as `new List<User>.from(...)`.
To create a typed list literal, you must write it as `<User>[new User(...)]`.

Comment: I can't find a difference between my code and this 'you must write it as `new List<User>.from(...)`' (beside the ...). I think I just don't get your comment.

Comment: My mistake. I wrote it originally as a comment to the original question, but decided it didn't add anything relevant, so I just made it a comment on your answer. The "you" should refer to the original question. Sorry about the confusion.